# IIS 7 url rewrite using database variables

Tags: database, url, iis-7, url-rewriting

I would like to change my urls from http://www.example.com/product.asp?productid=30 
to:
http://www.example.com/Samsung_LED_UE40D5000

the Samsung_LED_UE40D5000 is the product name + the product model stored in the database and is associated with the productid as the primary key.

how do i write a url rewrite rule to achieve that?
Thanks a lot!

O.B

Comment: The best way is to use Apache :) These links should help: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/iis7-url-rewrite-extension-on-windows-server-2008 http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/665/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference/

Answer (score 1):

You have to write **Custom Rewrite Provider** which accesses database to resolve product name + the product model to productId. Then use this Provider in your rewrite rules.

[Here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/804/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module/) is document describing the process.