# Is it possible for IIS 8 to query a database according to an URL in order to make a redirect?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, redirect, iis

Please, have patience if this question is long but I have never worked on this complex program which was developed by colleague of mine before I was recruited.

We have this web application running on .NET Framework v2.0 CLR. Anyway, this program is not natively written in C# but we must use a framework called Instant Developer which converts the code in a .NET application. The application runs in a Windows Server 2012 R2 under IIS 8 and with SQL Server 2014.

So, inside this application there is a very big directory called "photos" which contains a photo of each work a user completes. When the program was developed, our customer told us that very few photos were compulsory so my colleague thought that a unique directory was enough. But in this years the requirements have changed. Therefore, now a photo must be take for each work and so that directory today contains more than 5 millions of files. Consequently, it is not openable anymore by Windows Explorer, if I try the server blocks. Last month, our server was attacked by a crypto locker and my bosses decided to pay in order to get a decrypter otherwise our customer will ask us to pay a fine for each file which was lost. As soon as we have finished to recover our files, my boss asked to divide this huge directory into sub directories like /year/month/day. This can be easily done by a python script but the problem is that our customer registered in SAP a link to see that photo of this form

```
https://www.ourserver.it/applicationName/photo/file.jpg
```

and they told us they will refuse to change it. 
So, I would like to change the path of the photo in the database and, somehow, give instructions to IIS 8 in order that when it receives a URL like the previous, it should query the database, discover the new path and then redirect the client to a new URL like:

```
https://www.ourserver.it/applicationName/photo/year/month/day/file.jpg
```

This event is not catchable by the framework we use, that's why I need to program IIS in this way.

How can I achieve this? I don't care if I have to write code, not a problem. But if this could be done reasonably without going mad I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS 7 url rewrite using database variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740543/iis-7-url-rewrite-using-database-variables)

Comment: very kind of yours but I don't have visual studio

Comment: There is a ready-made DB-Provider mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37334133/205233) - if this specific one doesn't work with IIS8 anymore there surely is an other one that will.